# Changing the width of a categorized line layer with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I'm trying to change the width of a categorized line layer with PyQGIS.

Here is my code :

```
NOX_Actuel=iface.activeLayer()
target_field = 'NOX_Actuel'
myRangeList = []
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(NOX_Actuel.geometryType())
symbol.setColor(QColor("#67000d"))
myRange = QgsRendererRange(15.0, 500.0, symbol, '> 15')
myRangeList.append(myRange)
myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(target_field, myRangeList)
symbol.setWidth(5)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Custom)
NOX_Actuel.setRenderer(myRenderer)
NOX_Actuel.triggerRepaint()
```

Whatever I try, I've the following error : `"AttributeError: 'QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer' object has no attribute 'setWidth'"`

Answer (score 3):

You probably select a non-line layer before running the script. You should select a line layer. `QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol()` returns default symbol (`QgsMarkerSymbol`, `QgsFillSymbol` or `QgsLineSymbol`) for related geometry type.

The reason you get the error is that just `QgsLineSymbol` has `setWidth()` method, but `QgsMarkerSymbol` for points and `QgsFillSymbol` for polygons don't have.